# Script to update Flash Player?

Tags: macos, mac, script, flash-player

Is there script I can run in order to safely update Flash Player, on Mac OS X?
Without having to manually download, delete or do anything else?

Comment: and I was thinking this was a usefull question...

Answer (score 2):

Its not a script but its useful for more than just the Flash Player...try AppFresh

http://metaquark.de/appfresh/

Answer (score 1):

If you use Google Chrome, the newest versions come with Flash builtin and will update automatically to the latest.